# A keyboard shortcut for changing the Fill percentage in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I was wondering if there is a shortcut for changing the fill percentage in Photoshop. I know the shortcut to changing the opacity is pressing the numeric keys on the keyboard. Is there something similar for Fill also? Or is there a section in the Keyboard shortcuts , where I can create a new shortcut?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Shift key plus the numeric keys.

Comment: Hey thanks!  For some reason, that never came to my mind! Mindfarts I guess... Thanks anyways!